# How to remove Create and Edit... from many2one field.?

Tags: python, xml, one-to-many, odoo, many-to-one

Please advice me How to remove "Create and Edit..." from many2one field.?
that item shows below in the many2one fields which I filtered with domain option.

OpenERP version 7

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't have much idea. Maybe for that you have to make changes in web addons.

But an alternative solution is that you can make that **many2one** field **selection**. Add `widget="selection"` attribute in your xml.

`<field name="Your_many2one_field" widget="selection">`

Comment: Nice and easy solution , it is working for odoo-8 also , i tested there

Comment: If I want to change the domain of the field from fields_view_get(), so I have to remove the widget="selection". Then how this can be achieved?

Comment: Domain doesn't work on m2o field if widget selection is given.

Comment: I have done it by installing the web_m2x_options module and updating the domain from fields_view_get.

Comment: This solution should be the best but that widget has a problem, and is that if you have a lot of available records to select in the dropdown, it's going to show you only a few ones, and as the selection doesn't have a *Search more...* option, you'll never be able to select the rest ones.

Answer (score 20):

**Many2one widget (default)**

**Options** : Other possible options you can use with this widget.

- no_quick_create - It will remove Create "entered text" option.
- no_create_edit - It will remove Create and edit... option.
- no_create - no_quick_create and no_create_edit combined.
- no_open - in read mode: do not render as a link.

**Example**:

```
<field name="field_name" options="{'no_quick_create': True, 'no_create_edit' : True}"/>
```

You can refer it from [Ludwik Trammer's post](http://ludwiktrammer.github.io/odoo/form-widgets-many2one-fields-options-odoo.html)

Answer (score 6):

It is tested in openerp v7.0 , in which we can remove 'create and edit' by downloading a module present at,

https://www.odoo.com/apps/7.0/web_m2x_options/#access_token=31af017545174c1eb6745fa70c9b6684&scope=userinfo&state=&expires_in=3600&token_type=Bearer

and adding attribute 'create':false, 'create_edit': false like this

```
    <field name="partner_id" options="{'limit': 10, 'create': false, 'create_edit': false}"/>
```

A nice tutorial about this is given here 
https://www.odoo.com/apps/7.0/web_m2x_options/

Comment: ello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read the guidelines for good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer. One of the rules is to add context to links, instead of just pasting them. You should provide an answer that is valid without the need for the user to navigate to another side, but might wish to do so for more detail on the answer. That becomes a bigger problem when the links for some reason become invalid.

Answer (score 5):

For Odoo 8.0 and 9.0, you should use no_create and no_open.

`no_create:` Set to True to disable the option the create a new entry inside the drop down list.

`no_open:` Set to True to disable the button to the right of the drop down list which popup a windows allowing to edit the selected instance.

```
<field name="field_name"  options="{'no_create': True, 'no_open': True}" />
```

Answer (score 3):

In the xml file put:

```
<field name="my_field_name" options="{'no_create' : True}"/>
```

I hope this works!

Answer (score 3):

In the XML file:

Please add  ***options="{'no_create': True}"*** to your field which will remove the create button

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't want the 'selection' widget (it is less powerful, doesn't offer search capability) this is another method, tested in 8.

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_id']" position="attributes">
   <attribute name="options">{'no_create': '1', 'no_create_edit': '1'}</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add **no_open**, **no_create**, **no_create_edit**, in options

```
<field name="partner_id" options='{"no_open": True,"no_create": 1, "no_create_edit": 1}'/>
```

I tried it and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

In you XML file

```
<field name="your_field_name" options="{'no_quick_create':True,'no_create_edit':True,'no_open': True,}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for odoo here, for many2one relational field.

Works in listed below official odoo version, default feature.

- odoo 9
- odoo 10
- odoo 11

```xml
<field name="patient_id" options="{'no_quick_create': true, 'no_create_edit': false}"/>
```

Note:

- 'no_quick_create': true, disable inline creation feature, without
- popup 'no_create_edit': true, disable inline creation with popup
  features. 'no
- _create': true, diable inline and popup both with this only a option