# How to Hide Create and Create and edit Options in form view in odoo 11?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I am Added New field related with Many2one and when i am click on than it will show create and create and edit button so any one help me how to achieve.

My Filed Code :

```
 exam_course = field.Many2one('coures.type', string="Course")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Try below code and i think it's help you

```
<field name="field_name" options="{'no_create ': True, 'no_create_edit' : True}"/>
```

for more info you can try below link :

[How to remove Create and Edit... from many2one field.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630054/how-to-remove-create-and-edit-from-many2one-field/30590267#30590267)